# Pythonic way to solve a small task

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a function that returns values for some list of actions. I need to get an (action, value) tuple for a min or max value (depends on minmaxFunction).

minmaxFunction and could be either min or max:

```
minmaxFunction = min
or
minmaxFunction = max
```

Now I use:

```
bestValue = None
bestAction = None

for action in moves:
    subValue = someFunction(action)
    if bestValue is None or minmaxFunction(bestValue, subValue) != bestValue:
        bestValue = subValue
        bestAction = action

return bestAction, bestValue
```

I am pretty sure there is a better (pythonic) way to do it. Maybe something like

```
listOfTuples = [(action, someFunction(action)) for action in moves]
and here something with reduce() ????
```

Comment: Do you want the solution in Python 2.7 or Python 3.x? I guess having both tags could mean the solution could be in a different version than what you use currently.

Comment: Your code is incorrect: there is no indentation after `if` so it's unclear if one or two lines of code should be inside `if`. Furthermore, it looks like you don't expect us to write `minmaxFunction`; could you please provide its definition?

Comment: @juhist It will be interesting to have for both but really I need Python 2.7 . I have add a clarification for minmaxFunction

Comment: Out of curiosity, what game is this minimax algorithm for?

Comment: @Shashank it is an education task for Pacman

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use your `minmax` function just like you would use `min` or `max`:

```
lst = [-6,-5,-4,4,5,6]

def foo(x):
    return x*x

minmax = min

print minmax((foo(x), x) for x in lst)[1]  # -4
```

Answer (score 2):

Does this answer your question:

```
sorted([(action, someFunction(action)) for action in moves], key=lambda x:x[1])[0]
```

It sorts the list, using the second value of the tuple as the key, and then returns the first of the array. I wasn't completely sure if you want the first or the last; change `0` to `-1` for last.